# Hide android app without rooting

Tags: android

I am developing aan android application which hides pictures,music videos and applications. But I got a problem while application hiding module. By a good search i came to know that the phone must be rooted/unlocked for the application locking.
Is there is any way to hide applications in android without rooting/unlocking?

Comment: Are you looking for an existing app or a way to build that app?

Comment: a way to build new app. The file hiding modules cmpleted already. and the application hiding too. but the problem is the application hiding module works only if the rooting is done

Comment: no..no other way.. your application gets more permission if you have rooted device. But it is harmful to you also that other application get also benefits from it. :(

Comment: To be truthful, I used to have an app ["Hide it"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro)which did this and my device is not rooted. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score -1):

maybe if you make it so that you have to download the app thew your application, and saving it onto a file, in the phone, and not on the front interface of the phone, maybe when they take the picture of save it, it does to the directory of the aplictation

Comment: when they open your app, gives them the option to open an app, but if its saved on your appliction, and not viewed on the home screen